# insertion losses

Tags: signal

I know that attenuation doesn't change with frequency of signal. However, during my experiment, I found that there is a slight decrease in amplitude of signal when frequency is increased. Can anyone explain its why does it happen?

Comment: non-ideal (aka real world) attenuator. parasitic capacitance.

Comment: It would help tremendously to see what attenuator design & components you used. ... unless you'de like @brhans & I to spend the next three hours tag-team commenting on the thousands of possible reasons, given the lack of information provided. -- Reactance of resistor inductance in wire-wound or foil-wound resistors. ;)

Comment: Why have you edited your question to make it _less_ specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attenuator is made from resistors and is intended to have a flat frequency response. The resistors themselves are not ideal and can be approximated well by an ideal resistor with series inductance and parallel capacitance. Generally resistors in the middle of the value range closer to ideal. Series inductance mucks up low values because it's more significant in percentage terms. Parallel capacitance mucks up the high values for the same reasoning. It's now clear that the attenuators accuracy slowly worsens as frequency is increased.

When designing attenuators, large values like, say, 20dB are worse than, say, two 10dB sections. This is why expensive quality attenuators have lots of small sections. Unwanted coupling is much worse as frequency increases and is more significant when large attenuation figures are attempted in one section. Quality attenuators have good shielding between sections. Your attenuator is far from ideal because you see discrepancies at such low frequencies. Such an attenuator is good for college experiments where small departures from ideal are of educational value.

Answer (score 2):

That's really an awfully low frequency to be seeing significant changes, assuming a 50\$\Omega\$ (say pi) attenuator.

Even a sloppy (but very compact) attenuator for 10-20dB should be pretty flat to a GHz or more if made with thin film 0603 resistors.

If you're using inductive wirewound parts, the attenuator is high impedance, or it's physically large, that could explain it.

Answer (score 0):

Attenuation ALWAYS changes with the frequency of the signal, because everything is a filter. Everything physical is a filter of some kind, I can't stress this enough, materials are filters. Circuit theory is a nice way to model materials and the electrons that travel through them. In short you probably have a low pass filter of some kind. [Low Pass Filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-pass_filter) There are other ways to get filtering beside an RC, you have RLC, LC and transmission line effects that can attenuate signals